# Org mode link in comments

Tags: org-mode, comment, org-link

Is there a way to make links work in comments?

```
# Comment with [[link]]

link
```

## Error Message:

> edmacro-parse-keys: C-M- must prefix a single character, not up

The link would work only when separated from the comment.

```
# Comment with
[[link]]

link
```

## Specs:

> Org mode version 9.3.1 (9.3.1-elpa @ /Users/satibodhi/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20191230/)
>
> GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Links do work in comments.

Comment: When the link is placed within the comment, I get the error message indicated above, and the link is not responsive.

Comment: Please update your question with the version of emacs and org-mode in which you see this error? For emacs version you can use `M-x version`. For org-mode version, you can use `M-x org-version`. Thank you!

Comment: Updated. Any leads?

Comment: Works here with version 9.3.1. Try it with `emacs -q`.

Comment: It worked with `emacs -q`. Probably has something to do with my `init.el` settings.